# 'Are you sure you want to delete selected items OR the selected items?'?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

"Are you sure you want to delete selected items?"
or
"Are you sure you want to delete the selected items?"
Which one is correct?

Maybe it's better to say " delete these items" and to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2):

"The". Because they are specific.